# Add dll to Visual Basic project in VS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I have a .dll library that I need to add to a Visual Basic project. I already added it via "right click/Add/Com Reference..." and I see it in the VS window but the IDE keeps telling me that `Mylib.Mylibtype` doesn't exist.

```
Imports Mylib

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        Dim PCs As Mylib.Mylibtype
    End Sub
End Module
```

I added the `Imports Mylib` because I thought it was the source of this issue but it doesn't change anything.

I already had to add this library in a VS project in C# and didn't run into any issue.

Comment: can you give us a link to that library as we can test it ?

Comment: That's probably because it doesn't exist.  Use Object Browser to see the types that do exist in this library.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem came from a library provided by the program I'm using. There is a library of the same name in the `COM References` but it shouldn't be used.

I think I had to precise it to make sure people in a similar situation be careful to use the good library though I won't mark my answer as the good one because I think the problem is too specific for the answer to be really useful to most people.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing by "right click/Add/Com Reference..." , go to Project -> Add Reference and use Browse (the last one) to select your file.

If you already are seeing it and autocomplete shows his methods/properties then the library is loaded.
Make sure you are instancing it well creating a New instance.

```
Dim PCs As **New** Mylib.Mylibtype
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  Please consider formatting your code as code for improved readability.  Thanks!